# Uploading ASCX files via WebDAV in 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, webdav, 2011-sp1

I'm trying to set up an msbuild script that copies all the necessary binary content to the relevant folders in Tridion.

Everything is working as expected but having trouble when dealing with ASCX files.

JavaScript, CSS and images all upload fine using a simple copy to the folder but ASCX files cannot be uploading giving a file cannot be found error.

I've tried forcing the schema on certain folders and trying again but to no avail.

I've seen something similar with CSHTML and XSL files that cannot be uploaded as these file types are reserved for things like component templates.  This would make sense for ASCX files as well but these upload fine when using the normal content manager interface.

Anyone have any idea as to why ASCX files are a special case?  Do I need to write something custom using the core service for this instead?

Comment: Do the ascx files necessarily need to exist in the CMS? This sounds like a requirement to be able to "publish" functionality (code) along with content from SDL Tridion's interface. Could this be a custom page or a GUI extension instead (unless you really need component linking, CM history, and other CMS features)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this a while ago and seem to remember it being to do with .ASCX files not being allowed to be uploaded in to IIS via WebDav because of Request Filtering.

> All of the request filtering features can impact content that is
>   uploaded or download through WebDAV

I think that this can be changed in the `applicationHost.config` file

```
<requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true">
                <add fileExtension=".asa" allowed="false" />
                <add fileExtension=".asax" allowed="false" />
                **<add fileExtension=".ascx" allowed="true" />**
...
<requestFiltering>
```

There is more information on this on the Learn IIS site [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-webdav/how-to-configure-webdav-with-request-filtering).

Comment: Worked a treat, cheers JDubz

Comment: Superb.  Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Step one is to make sure that ASCX is a valid mime type (or a valid extension for an existing mimetype), and has a Multimedia schema using it for the folder you are uploading to.

In addition, I have seen Visual Studio create lots of temporary files when copying and saving to WebDAV. In order to make saving to WedDAV work, check the event viewer to see what is a actually getting saves, you may need to add a number of additional extensions/MimeTypes to SDL Tridion to make this work.